# Deserializing JSON data with flexible key and type into structures

Tags: rust

I need to parse JSON data that's got a... unique structure. It either looks like this:

```
{"ok": true, "<key>": .... }
```

or this

```
{"ok": false, "error": "reason" }
```

Where `<key>` and the shape of the data *depends* on the API call.

The following code accomplishes this task, assuming that `T` derives `Deserialize` from serde. However, it does not use `serde` to accomplish this. How might you alter this code to make it more idiomatic?

Whilst you are free to review any part of the code as per your remit, please note that the name `RawResponse2` originates because I was hacking this together to identify a solution; it's not reflective of an actual name I would use, although, regardless, this name would not be exposed to any caller.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Error {
    MalformedResponse,
    Serde(serde_json::Error),
    Slack(Reason),
}

#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
struct RawResponse2<T> {
    ok: bool,
    err: Option<Reason>,
    val: Option<T>,
}

impl<T> From<RawResponse2<T>> for Result<T, Error> {
    // We cannot have OK=false, Err=None, or OK=true and Err=Some|Data=None.
    // If any of these things happen, we have a malformed response
    fn from(val: RawResponse2<T>) -> Self {
        match val {
            RawResponse2 {
                ok: true,
                val: Some(v),
                ..
            } => Ok(v),
            RawResponse2 {
                ok: false,
                err: Some(reason),
                ..
            } => Err(Error::Slack(reason)),
            _ => Err(Error::MalformedResponse),
        }
    }
}

trait DeserializableValue<'a>: DeserializeOwned {
    fn tag_name() -> &'a str;
}

fn from_json<'a, T>(value: &Value) -> Result<T, Error>
where
    T: DeserializableValue<'a>,
{
    // We need to exchange res for a value. This _should_ be an object with up to three keys:
    // * ok (bool)
    // * error (optional, string)
    // * <indeterminate key name> (optional, <interdeterminate type>)
    let (ok, err, val) = match value {
        Value::Object(map) => {
            let ok = map.get("ok").and_then(|v| v.as_bool());
            let err = map
                .get("error")
                .map(|e| Reason::deserialize(e).map_err(Error::Serde));
            let tag = T::tag_name();
            let val = map
                .get(tag)
                .map(|v| T::deserialize(v).map_err(Error::Serde));

            Ok((ok, err, val))
        }
        _ => Err(Error::MalformedResponse),
    }?;

    // Now we can convert this into the intermediate representation, which is converted
    // to a Result via From
    RawResponse2 {
        // ok can never be absent - if it is, something has gone wrong, and it should be considered an error.
        ok: ok.ok_or(Error::MalformedResponse)?,
        // val can be absent (None), present but parsed incorrectly (Some(Err(_)), or present and parsed correctly (Some(Ok(_))).
        val: match val {
            None => None,
            Some(Ok(val)) => Some(val),
            Some(Err(e)) => return Err(e),
        },
        // Similarly, err has the same branches..
        err: match err {
            None => None,
            Some(Ok(val)) => Some(val),
            Some(Err(e)) => return Err(e),
        },
    }
    .into()
}
```

How would *you* approach this problem? As best I can tell, I cannot use `#[serde(untagged)]` to solve this, so I wrote the deserialization code myself.

Here's a test which demonstrates that this code works:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Eq, PartialEq)]
struct TestWebSocketInfo(String);
impl<'a> DeserializableValue<'a> for TestWebSocketInfo {
    fn tag_name() -> &'a str {
        "url"
    }
}

fn typeck<'a, T>(blob: &'a &str) -> Result<T, Error>
where
    T: DeserializableValue<'a> + std::fmt::Debug,
{
    let res = serde_json::from_str::<Value>(blob)?;
    let t: T = from_json(&res)?;
    Ok(t)
}

#[test]
fn derives_slack_response_correctly() {
    let ok_blob = r#"{"ok": true, "url": "wss://example.com/socket"}"#;
    assert_eq!(
        TestWebSocketInfo("wss://example.com/socket".to_string()),
        typeck(ok_blob).unwrap()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let err = map
    .get("error")
    .map(|e| Reason::deserialize(e).map_err(Error::Serde));
```

You have an `Option<Error<...>>` and end up with fairly complicated logic to handle it later. Instead, I'd just using the `transpose()` method which converts `Option<Error<..>>` into `Error<Option<...>>`

```
 let err = map.get("error").map(Reason::deserialize).transpose()?;
```

Then you can just deal with an option later.

Your whole intermediate representation is kinda pointless. Just convert directly to the desired form. Something like:

```
match (ok, val, err) {
    (Some(true), Some(val), None) => Ok(val),
    (Some(false), None, Some(error)) => Err(Error::Slack(error)),
    _ => Err(Error::MalformedResponse)
}
```

But there is bit of an inefficiency in your code:

```
fn from_json<'a, T>(value: &Value) -> Result<T, Error>
```

With this implementation, the complete JSON has to be deserialized into a `Value` before being redeserialized into the target type. It'd be nice to skip that. You by implementing custom deserialization logic as explained here: https://serde.rs/deserialize-struct.html